# Do I need mutex read lock when retrieving slice values with context in Go?

Tags: go

I have been reading about context and passing values in middlewares. Since the julienschmidt httprouter is not compatible with http.Handler interface I thought I could save the httprouter `Params` which is a slice of `Param`

https://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Params

and save this in a context value and retrieve later.

The Go blog article on context: https://blog.golang.org/context says that:

> Value allows a Context to carry request-scoped data. That data must be
>   safe for simultaneous use by multiple goroutines.

I don't know if this data is safe. Slices are not thread safe as I understand, but how would multiple go routines access the data in this situation?

I have a handler that converts http.Handler to httprouter.Handle and saves the httprouter.Params so that I can use those params in http.HandlerFunc type functions.

```
type ctxKey string

var paramKey ctxKey = "params"

func paramHandler(h http.Handler) httprouter.Handle {
    return httprouter.Handle(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), paramKey, ps)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

var mutex sync.RWMutex

func params(r *http.Request) httprouter.Params {
    // https://blog.golang.org/context
    // "Value allows a Context to carry request-scoped data.
    // That data must be safe for simultaneous use by multiple goroutines."
    mutex.RLock()
    value := r.Context().Value(paramKey)
    mutex.RUnlock()
    if ps, ok := value.(httprouter.Params); ok {
        return ps
    }
    return httprouter.Params{}
}
```

In paramHandler I set the context value which is a slice of httprouter.Param, and in params(r *http.Request) function I receive the parameters.

My question is, do I need write locks when saving the slice of params in context in paramHandler, and read locks when retrieving the params from context as I have in the function param(*http.Request)?

I plan on retrieving the params like this:

```
func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ps := params(r)
    fmt.Println(ps.ByName("id"))
}
```

Are the locks necessary?

Comment: Where in your code do you access the context concurrently?

Comment: I don't access it concurrently as I showed on the post that I could use it in a getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) type of function, I don't try to access it concurrently, but I thought maybe something happened in the background without me knowing. Since the go article says it needs to be thread safe.

Comment: What it means is that `context` does not synchronise access for you (even though its own methods are thread-safe). So if you intend to pass the same context object to multiple goroutines then it would be your responsibility to properly synchronise access to the context value that you store.

Comment: So if I just use it inside an http.HandlerFunc for requests and response as I showed at the end of the post, then I won't need it right? Just access it in a simple way, not in multiple go routines from my part.

Comment: It looks like not. https://golang.org/src/context/context.go?s=14784:14844#L443 there is nothing in the code that would require external synchronisation - it is simply a constructor function that sets a value, and a function to read it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are worried about a data race. Here is something helpful on the golang blog:

> Data races are among the most common and hardest to debug types of
>   bugs in concurrent systems. A data race occurs when two goroutines
>   access the same variable concurrently and at least one of the accesses
>   is a write.

The introduction to the [race detector blog entry](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

So if you are not sure you can run the race detector. Because it is not complicated. Just set the flag `-race` and go will check if there is a data race.

When you use context normally you don't need to lock, because is passed through all the calls and for every new call there will be another address inside the memory.

If you always read from a variable you don't need to lock it, because then the value will never change.