# Getting a panic from a production server made in Go

Tags: go

I am getting a panic which I try to understand but I am not really sure why it panics. The error looks like this:

```
main.HTTPSNonWWWRedirect.func1(0x9a5a20, 0xc42015c2a0, 0xc420441400)
        /srv/www/go/src/srorapp.no/handler.go:119 +0x1ef
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc4200c5f20, 0x9a5a20, 0xc42015c2a0, 0xc420441400)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1918 +0x44
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc4200696c0, 0x9a5a20, 0xc42015c2a0, 0xc420441400)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2619 +0xb4
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc42006d180, 0x9a5fa0, 0xc42031e840)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x71d
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2720 +0x288
```

It looks like it is being fired from a function called HTTPSNonWWWRedirect. Which is a http middleware that I have created:

```
// HTTPSNonWWWRedirect redirects http requests to https non www.
func HTTPSNonWWWRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.TLS != nil {
            // If already using HTTPS then continue.
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        u := *r.URL
        u.Scheme = "https"
        if r.Host[:3] != "www" {
            u.Host = r.Host
            http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
            return
        }
        u.Host = r.Host[4:]
        http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
}
```

This function is being used alongside with:

```
// NonWWWRedirect redirects www requests to non www.
func NonWWWRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Host[:3] != "www" {
            // If already non www, then continue.
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        u := *r.URL
        u.Host = r.Host[4:]
        u.Scheme = utils.Scheme(r)
        http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
}
```

And then I have two functions that serves from port 80 and 443.

```
func serveHTTP(h http.Handler) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", h))
}

func serveHTTPS(h http.Handler) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", cfg.TLSCertFile, cfg.TLSKeyFile, h))
}
```

I have made a wrapper around julienschmidt httprouter to make things more convenient:

```
// https://gist.github.com/nmerouze/5ed810218c661b40f5c4
type router struct {
    r *httprouter.Router
}

func newRouter() *router {
    return &router{r: httprouter.New()}
}
```

In main I have something like this:

```
func main() {
    router := newRouter()
    recover := alice.New(recoverHandler)    

    // ....

    redirect := alice.New(HTTPSNonWWWRedirect, NonWWWRedirect)
    handler := redirect.Then(router.r)
    go serveHTTP(handler)
    serveHTTPS(handler) 
}
```

Here are the contents of handler.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"

    cfg "srorapp.no/config"
    "srorapp.no/user"
    "srorapp.no/utils"
)

// https://gist.github.com/nmerouze/5ed810218c661b40f5c4
type router struct {
    r *httprouter.Router
}

func newRouter() *router {
    return &router{r: httprouter.New()}
}

var paramsKey utils.CtxKey = "params"

func paramsHandler(h http.Handler) httprouter.Handle {
    return httprouter.Handle(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), paramsKey, ps)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

// https://www.calhoun.io/pitfalls-of-context-values-and-how-to-avoid-or-mitigate-them/
func params(r *http.Request) httprouter.Params {
    // https://blog.golang.org/context
    // "Value allows a Context to carry request-scoped data.
    // That data must be safe for simultaneous use by multiple goroutines."
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893937/do-i-need-mutex-read-lock-when-retrieving-slice-values-with-context-in-go?noredirect=1#comment72889988_42893937
    // Do not need a mutex here since I will access it in a simple way and not concurrently.
    value := r.Context().Value(paramsKey)
    if ps, ok := value.(httprouter.Params); ok {
        return ps
    }
    return httprouter.Params{}
}

func (r *router) GET(path string, handler http.Handler) {
    r.r.GET(path, paramsHandler(handler))
}

func (r *router) POST(path string, handler http.Handler) {
    r.r.POST(path, paramsHandler(handler))
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type errorHandlerFunc func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871194/how-can-i-combine-go-middleware-pattern-with-error-returning-request-handlers/42876307#42876307
func errorHandler(h errorHandlerFunc) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Set Content-Type to plain text when sending http.Error.
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        if err := h(w, r); err != nil {
            // w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
            // http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
            log.Println(err)
        }
    })
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/middleware/redirect.go
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916952/do-you-have-to-return-after-a-http-redirect-if-you-want-the-code-after-to-stop-e
// https://play.golang.org/p/uk0S1hCPhu

// HTTPSRedirect redirects HTTP to HTTPS.
func HTTPSRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.TLS != nil {
            // If already using HTTPS then continue.
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        http.Redirect(w, r, "https://"+r.Host+r.RequestURI, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
}

// HTTPSWWWRedirect redirects http requests to https www.
func HTTPSWWWRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.TLS != nil {
            // If already using HTTPS then continue.
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        u := *r.URL // Dereference *url.URL to make a copy.
        u.Scheme = "https"
        u.Host = "www." + strings.TrimPrefix(r.Host, "www.")
        http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
}

// HTTPSNonWWWRedirect redirects http requests to https non www.
func HTTPSNonWWWRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.TLS != nil {
            // If already using HTTPS then continue.
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        u := *r.URL
        u.Scheme = "https"
        if r.Host[:3] != "www" {
            u.Host = r.Host
            http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
            return
        }
        u.Host = r.Host[4:]
        http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
}

// WWWRedirect redirects non www requests to www.
func WWWRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Host[:3] == "www" {
            // If already www, then continue.
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        u := *r.URL
        u.Host = "www." + r.Host
        u.Scheme = utils.Scheme(r)
        http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
}

// NonWWWRedirect redirects www requests to non www.
func NonWWWRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Host[:3] != "www" {
            // If already non www, then continue.
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        u := *r.URL
        u.Host = r.Host[4:]
        u.Scheme = utils.Scheme(r)
        http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })
}

func canServeGzip(r *http.Request) bool {
    if !strings.Contains(r.Header.Get("Accept-Encoding"), "gzip") {
        // If for some weird reason client does not understand gzip.
        return false
    }
    path := filepath.FromSlash(filepath.Join(cfg.PublicHTML, r.URL.Path))
    if _, err := os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        // If file or folder does not exists.
        return false
    }
    fileExt := filepath.Ext(r.URL.Path)
    if !utils.StringInSlice(cfg.GzipFileExt, fileExt) {
        // This file should not be served as gzipped content.
        return false
    }
    // Only serve gzipped file if it already exists.
    if _, err := os.Stat(path + ".gz"); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        // TODO: Create the gzipped file.
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890648/how-can-i-use-golangs-compress-gzip-package-to-gzip-a-file
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func gzipHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        if !canServeGzip(r) {
            // fmt.Println("as original", r.URL.Path)
            return
        }
        w.Header().Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", contentType(filepath.Ext(r.URL.Path)))
        r.URL.Path = r.URL.Path + ".gz"
        // fmt.Println("as gzip", r.URL.Path)
    })
}

func recoverHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                log.Printf("panic: %+v\n", err)
                http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        }()
        // time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

var userIDKey utils.CtxKey = "userID"

func authHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        userID, err := user.IsLoggedIn(r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("main authHandler() %v", err)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized), http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), userIDKey, userID)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

func adminHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 600)
        isLoggedInAsAdmin, err := user.IsLoggedInAsAdmin(r)
        if err != nil || !isLoggedInAsAdmin {
            if !isLoggedInAsAdmin {
                log.Printf("main adminHandler() User is not logged in as admin %v", err)
            } else {
                log.Printf("main adminHandler() %v", err)
            }
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized), http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), userIDKey, 1)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func serveDevHTTP(h http.Handler) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", h))
    // log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", h))
}

func serveHTTP(h http.Handler) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", h))
}

func serveHTTPS(h http.Handler) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", cfg.TLSCertFile, cfg.TLSKeyFile, h))
}
```

I am not sure how to debug this panic.

Comment: Can you please paste the full error log? there should be some error message above the stack trace

Comment: I had cleared error log before I started the server, and the only thing that is visible is only the panic error, so no errors prior to that.

Comment: can you tell me which code is `handler.go:119` ?

Comment: I updated the post and added the whole handler.go file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. The Problem

The `handler.go:119` contains an `if` statement. You tried to get the first three characters from the `Host` header.

```
if r.Host[:3] != "www" {
    u.Host = r.Host
    http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    return
}
```

Normally, the `r.Host` will store the request URL information. **Unless** the `Host` header explicitly changed on the request. From the [net/http package doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request):

```
type Request struct {
    // ...

    // For server requests Host specifies the host on which the URL
    // is sought. Per RFC 7230, section 5.4, this is either the value
    // of the "Host" header or the host name given in the URL itself.
    // It may be of the form "host:port". For international domain
    // names, Host may be in Punycode or Unicode form. Use
    // golang.org/x/net/idna to convert it to either format if
    // needed.
    // To prevent DNS rebinding attacks, server Handlers should
    // validate that the Host header has a value for which the
    // Handler considers itself authoritative. The included
    // ServeMux supports patterns registered to particular host
    // names and thus protects its registered Handlers.
    //
    // For client requests Host optionally overrides the Host
    // header to send. If empty, the Request.Write method uses
    // the value of URL.Host. Host may contain an international
    // domain name.
    Host string

    // ...
}
```

So the panic is occurring because `r.Host` filled with empty string, or some string that the character count is lower than 3.

### 2. Testing

I created very simple web application using go that prints the value of `r.Host[:3]`. I tested it using curl, with `Host` header set to empty.

```
curl --verbose --header 'Host: ' http://localhost:8080
```

It triggers a panic, and I'm pretty sure it's the same panic error like what you get.

```
2018/12/07 08:11:54 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:50889: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
goroutine 37 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0001380a0)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1746 +0xd0
panic(0x125c0c0, 0x14964d0)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
main.main.func1(0x12efa80, 0xc00014c2a0, 0xc000162300)
    /Users/novalagung/Desktop/test.go:11 +0x13d
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12bcd98, 0x12efa80, 0xc00014c2a0, 0xc000162300)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1964 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x14a17a0, 0x12efa80, 0xc00014c2a0, 0xc000162300)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2361 +0x127
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000093110, 0x12efa80, 0xc00014c2a0, 0xc000162300)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2741 +0xab
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0001380a0, 0x12efc80, 0xc000146100)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1847 +0x646
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2851 +0x2f5
```

### 3. Solution

The solution is quite simple, just make sure that the `r.Host` value is not an empty string and the length is greater than 2. Better use `strings.HasPrefix()` to get this done.

```
if strings.HasPrefix(r.Host, "www") {
    u.Host = r.Host
    http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    return
}
```

Comment: What should I do if the r.Host is empty? Should I just return without calling next.ServeHTTP or should I run an http error? Any advice there?

Comment: @Alex, [the Host header is required](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4). How you want to deal with a missing header is up  to you, but one would typically send some 400 response.

Comment: @Alex [A Host header field must be sent in all HTTP/1.1 request messages. A 400 (Bad Request) status code will be sent to any HTTP/1.1 request message that lacks a Host header field or contains more than one.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host)